# how to set read only properties to the particular info path form control based on user logged in?

Tags: forms, infopath

how to set read only properties to the  particular info path form control based on user logged in?

Comment: Are you looking to do it programmatically or through the use of OOB InfoPath logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option (assuming you are using managed code) is to get the user name with either `Application.User.UserName` or `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` and then call `IsInRole` (I believe it is a member of the WindowsPrincipal class).

Save the result into the value of a field and you can then use the standard conditional formatting to lock the fields you don't want the users changing. I also usually conditionally change the look of those readonly fields (grey background fill etc) so the users don't get confused and think they can edit.